# What is the meaning of this code generated by IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, disassemblers, nasm

Test platform is Linux 32 bit.

I use IDA Pro to disassembly the basename from coreutils 8.5
 compiled by gcc 4.6.3

Here is a code snippet generated by IDA Pro

```
           call    _i686_get_pc_thunk_bx                                 
           add     ebx, 292Eh
           sub     esp, 18h
           mov     eax, ds:(__dso_handle_ptr - 804DFF4h[ebx]
           test    eax, eax
           jz      short loc_804B6F8
           mov     eax, [eax]

     loc_804B6DB:
           mov     [esp+1Ch+var_14], eax
           mov     eax, [esp+1Ch+arg_0]
           mov     dword [esp+1Ch+var_18], 0
           mov     [esp+1Ch+var_1C], eax
           call    __cxa_atexit
           add     esp, 18h
           pop     ebx
           retn

     loc_804B6F8:
           xor     eax, eax
           jmp     short loc_804B6DB
```

I don't understand this line:

```
mov     eax, ds:(__dso_handle_ptr - 804DFF4h[ebx]
```

and after searching the code, I can only find this:

```
        __dso_handle    dd 0
```

in the .data section.

So my questions are:

1. What is the meaning of this line..?  Is it like a version checking stuff..?
2. Can I just safely remove this line without affecting the functionality of the code..?

Comment: You should *really* add more context!

Comment: Can you please post at least the whole ```main``` of basename?

Comment: @ph0sec Thank you and I can modify the question later. But basically I modify my IDC scripts to directly generate nasm syntax asm, then this problem gone....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking at binary that is compiled as position-independent code. The `call    _i686_get_pc_thunk_bx` and the following addition to `ebx` shows just that. If you take a look at the disassembly, you'll see that the address of the `add ebx, 292Eh` plus 0x292E will result in the first address of the GOT. That why in the next line, _dso_handle_ptr is addressed in such a "funny" way.

IDA however is nice enough to show you this in the disassembly as you would normally only see 0xSOMEADDR[ebx].

In terms of the second question: that line retrieves a global variable, puts it into `eax` and then checks if it is zero or not. So, you should not just "delete" that line since then the `test eax, eax` would use some old value of `eax` (which I am sure you will not like all that much).